# Book on Mathematical Optimisation

Tags: optimization, book-recommendation

I need a book on mathematical optimisation which covers as many topics from the following list as possible:

- Introduction (Graphs, Paths, Network Planning, Spanning Trees, Matchings),
- Matroids (Independence Systems and Matroids, Bases, Circuits and Ranks, Maximization over Independence Systems and Matroids Minimization over Bases Systems)
- Running Time of Algorithms (Algorithms, Encoding Length, Polynomial-time Algorithms, first Polynomial-time Computations),
- Dynamic Programming (Multilevel Decision Processes, Knapsack Problem, Shortest Walks and Paths),
- Optimization in Networks (Flows and Cuts, Augmentation, Algorithm of Dinic),
- Elements of Complexity Theory

It would also be helpful if you could tell me the prerequisite background for the same.

Comment: Seems like you are only interested in discrete optimization?

Comment: I agree, it sounds like you are interested in Discrete Optimization, and the question is more likely to survive if the title is changed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The book [Combinatorial Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity](https://books.google.com.sg/books/about/Combinatorial_Optimization.html?id=u1RmDoJqkF4C&redir_esc=y) by Papadimitriou and Steiglitz covers much of what you require. It is a little bit dated perhaps (written in 1982) but well-written and pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the books that would cover everything, but I can suggest one good book and one review through which you can find other useful sources.
Hope this helps.

[Multilevel decision-making: A survey](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025516300202)

[Multilevel Optimization: Algorithms and Applications](https://books.google.ru/books?id=zNAwFXUOdgsC&pg=PA150&dq=Multilevel%20Decision%20Processes&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_5sKTiu7jAhVy-SoKHSplBmYQ6AEIcDAJ#v=onepage&q=Multilevel%20Decision%20Processes&f=false)